# Using SendMessage to send filepath/filename to Save Dialog Box, but file not changing from default when save button is clicked

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I am using `SendMessage()` to send a filepath/filename to a SaveAs dialog box.  Using `SendMessage()`, the edit box is updated with the correct file path and name.  But when the Save button click is pressed, an error message is shown with the filepath/filename shown as the original default when the SaveAs dialog box was first open.

It appears that when the filename field is updated, it show the text but it is not being refreshed in the background.  When the save button is pressed it is still using the default filename.

How/why is the window not noticing the change of the edit field?

The dialog box works fine using `SendKeys`, or manually typing in the file name.

```
Sub TestSaveAs()
Dim ParentHwnd As Long
Dim ChildHwnd As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim strText As String
Dim lngRet As Long
Dim filepath As String

strText = String$(100, Chr$(0))
filepath = "test"

'Saveas window is currently open
ParentHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Save project")
ChildHwnd = FindWindowEx(ParentHwnd, 0&, vbNullString, vbNullString)
For x = 1 To 10 'Find Editbox for filename/path
    ChildHwnd = FindWindowEx(ChildHwnd, 0&, vbNullString, vbNullString)
    lngRet = GetClassName(ChildHwnd, strText, 100)
    If left$(strText, lngRet) = "Edit" Then
        SendMessage ChildHwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, ByVal filepath 'Sucessfully updates SaveAs Dialog Box
        Exit For
        End If
    Next x

ChildHwnd = FindWindowEx(ParentHwnd, 0&, vbNullString, vbNullString)
For x = 1 To 10 ' Find &Save Button
    ChildHwnd = FindWindowEx(ParentHwnd, ChildHwnd, vbNullString, vbNullString)
    lngRet = GetWindowText(ChildHwnd, strText, 100)
    If left$(strText, lngRet) = "&Save" Then
        Debug.Print UpdateWindow(ChildHwnd)
        SendMessage ChildHwnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0 'Sucessfully sends Save Button Click
        Exit For
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Here is the SaveAs error showing the Edit Box with a different filename:

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a little information about what you are trying to do? If you're just trying to run a save as on an Excel sheet, it doesn't have to be this hard.

Comment: It is a save as on an external program.   Excel is hosting the VBA but I am trying to send a save as on another program that does not have a VBA interface.

Comment: My condolences. I would recommend a tool made for that job. In this case: [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @HackSlash, thanks I may need to go that route.

Comment: Rather UIAutomation seems like what you need

Comment: Interestingly, using AutoIt if I use ContolSetText I reproduce the same issue.  If I use controlsend it works, whatever is happening in the background of the dialog box is updated and saves to the given location.   SendMessage appears to be similar to ControlSetText in AutoIt, is there a winapi similar to AutoIt's controlsend?

Comment: I got the same problem when trying to target a Save As Dialog. Anyone has a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you send the BM_CLICK to the child itself.

Send a WM_COMMAND BN_CLICK with the Id of the child to the parent of the button.

Comment: The "Save" button click works as expected.   When I manually typing in the file save path in the Saveas dialog then run the script,  the save button click works and the file is saved to the location manually typed.  Just not when the file location is dynamically entered into the edit box via SendMessage.